# Recharge my Component in Angular

Tags: angular

I am having a problem :

When my app in angular starts I get all registers from server and show, very well , this runs, But when I insert a new register and I call the function my var doesnt updated with the new register in Server.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
}
```

---

```
private fetchData() {
    console.log('entro');
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/getAll';
    this.service.fetchData(url).subscribe(data => {
        this.params = data;
    });
    console.log(this.params); //
}
```

---

When my app runs `this.params` is undefined, but I can see datas in my dropbox :S , Then Second call , I can see registers a except the new add

```
addConfig(formAddConfig) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/create';
    let newConfig:  ....
    this.service.addConfig(url, newConfig).subscribe(qhp => {
        console.log(qhp); 
    });

    this.fetchData();
}
```

I get message confirmation from server.

I need when I insert a new register in my server, updated my frontEnd with the new Register.

service-Angular:

```
public fetchData(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
}
```

In my BBDD I can get the new insert. the problem is show the new register in Angular4. I tried then the insert again to call `fechData()` but doesn't run...

Comment: try to move this.fetchData(); inside your subscription block,   this.service.addConfig(url, newConfig).subscribe(qhp => {
                    console.log(qhp);  this.fetchData();
                });

Comment: Yes, perfect thanks